# Given X and Y are correlated and Y and Z are correlated what is the range of correlation between X and Z?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, correlation

How can I calculate the range of correlation of two variables X and Z given I have the correlations of X and Y, and Y and Z?

I've found a few resources around, namely [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20171026064532/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/62860.html), but I'd like a research paper (if any).

Thanks!

Comment: would a textbook do?

Comment: Yes absolutely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correlation is the cosine of an angle.

Let
$$
\bar x = \frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}\text{ and }\bar y = \frac{y_1+\cdots+y_n}{n}.
$$
Then the correlation is the cosine of the angle between these two vectors:
$$
(x_1-\bar x, \ldots, x_n-\bar x)\text{ and } (y_1-\bar y, \ldots, y_n-\bar y).
$$

If you have the angles between $x$ and $y$ and between $y$ and $z$, then the angle between $x$ and $z$ cannot exceed the sum of those two, nor can it be less in absolute value than the difference between those two.  It can be anywhere in between.

There is a book by Danny Kaplan that has a chapter about this.  I think the word "statistics" is in the title.

Comment: So the range would be `|cos(x,y)-cos(y,z)| <= cos(x,z) <= cos(x,y)+cos(y,z)`?

Comment: @Ubobo : $\arccos(\operatorname{cor}(X,Y))$ is the angle you're looking for.  Once you're done adding or subtracting angles, take their cosines to get correlations.

Comment: Ah thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

The *average* of the three correlations $\rho_{X,Y}$, $\rho_{Y,Z}$, and
$\rho_{X,Z}$ must be $-\frac{1}{2}$ or more (cf. [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/72795/6633) on stats.SE) and so
$$\max\left\{-1, -\frac{3+ 2\rho_{X,Y} +2 \rho_{Y,Z}}{2}\right\} \leq \rho_{X,Z} \leq 1.$$